# Is there a Stack Exchange notification app for Windows 7?

Tags: support, app-request, notifier, windows

Is there a Stack Exchange notification app for Windows 7?

Comment: None of the items below allow you to just monitor for new questions, or questions based on a tag (or tags). There is a "[New Q](http://stackapps.com/questions/587/new-q-google-chrome-extension-notifies-you-of-new-questions-of-interest)" app in stackapps, which works moderately well, but has some annoying quirks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[StackApplet](https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-stackoverflow-meets-the-gnome-desktop-now-available-for-windows) is now available for Windows. It will notify you of any reputation changes, comments, and new answers - and all StackExchange sites are supported.

Comment: How about new questions matching a tag?

Answer (score 4):

There sure is.

*From the application page:*

## [StackTracker](https://stackapps.com/questions/290/stacktracker-cross-platform-desktop-notification-app)

> StackTracker, a cross-platform desktop notifier for the StackExchange API built with PyQt4

According to the page, Windows is a supported platform.

Comment: Ya, I've briefly tested it on Windows 7 and it seemed to work fine (I am the author of StackTracker).

Comment: @swanson: I know :)