# Stack Exchange notification app for Windows 10 (integration with Action Center)

Tags: support, app-request, notifier

Is there a Stack Exchange notification app (particularly, the inbox) for Windows 10 that has integration with [Action Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Center?oldformat=true)?

There are [notification apps for Windows 7](https://stackapps.com/questions/1682/is-there-a-stack-exchange-notification-app-for-windows-7) that I am currently using, but I'd prefer if they don't take space on the taskbar.