# Is there an equivalent to SOStatus app for any Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, mac-os-x

Before I reinvent a wheel, is there an equivalent to the SOStatus app that can show reputation on any Stack Exchange site?

SOStatus gives the status of a user on Stack Overflow.

It would also be nice to be shown if there were new responses/comments.

Comment: This should be asked on meta.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Now that there is an answer, can I leave it here? I'll know beta next time (pun)...

Comment: This question actually isn't even specific to Ask Different, so while it's wildly off topic on AD Main, it's not explicitly most on topic at Ask Different Meta. All aboard the Stack Apps train (along with the entirely correct answer, IMO, as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On http://stackapps.com several [Mac OS X](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app+mac-os-x) applications are listed. StackApps is the StackExchange API and application and scripts site.

Personally, I use [Newt](https://stackapps.com/questions/1993/newt-question-answer-and-comment-and-rep-change-notifications-for-mac-os-x), which can display new questions, comment notifications and reputation changes from across all the StackExchange sites, including AskDifferent.

To answer some points raised [elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/142637/how-does-the-sostatus-app-work-osx):

- The SOStatus app most likely uses the [StackExchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com).
- I don't think it is Open Source; the developer does not list it on it's [Open Source software page](http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/) nor is there any trace of it on their [GitHub account](https://github.com/macmade/).