# Stackpop — Stack Exchange meets OS X Notification Center

Tags: app, mac-os-x

[image: Stackpop notification]

Stack Exchange meets OS X Notification Center. Keep up to date with all the most recent activity regarding your questions, answers, and more with Stackpop, an OS X application that lives in the menu bar.

#### Download

https://www.jacobbudin.com/static/files/stackpop/stackpop-1c.zip (.zip, 210KB)

#### Source

https://bitbucket.org/jacobbudin/stackpop/

#### Features

- Works with all Stack Exchange sites
- Checks every five minutes for new inbox items, notifications, and reputation changes
- Links directly to content (e.g., clicking a "Post Upvoted" notification loads the post)
- Uses OS X Notification Center
- Retina-quality assets
- Code signed by developer and [sandboxed](https://www.apple.com/osx/what-is/security.html)

#### System requirements

- Mac OS X 10.9 "Mavericks"

#### Change log

- v1.0c (Dec 1, 2014) – final release, removed expiration period
- v1.0b (Mar 31, 2014) – extended beta period
- v1.0 public beta (Feb 9, 2014) — initial release

#### Developer

[Jacob Budin](http://www.jacobbudin.com)

[image: Stackpop preference pane]

Comment: What happens after the beta expires? And how does your app compare to [Newt](http://stackapps.com/q/1993) (which is admittedly getting a little long in the tooth)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'll release a new version. Stackpop embraces  10.9-era technologies (app sandbox, Notification Center, Retina).

Comment: I'll have to upgrade to 10.9 finally then if only to test. How does it handle reputation from per-site metas? Outside of meta.stackoverflow.com accounts on meta don't have independent reputation, but Newt does echo rep changes on those as the reputation is synched once an hour.

Comment: thanx this is awesome app, but i have trouble after install and launch,  `too many requests from your ip` if i open browser and go to stackexchange.

Comment: @Monk_Code You must have other apps, scripts, or sites using the Stack Exchange API under your username. Try clicking the "Apps" link in your Stack Exchange user panel and removing those you aren't using anymore.

Comment: Feature request: if the user chooses to authenticate via Facebook, it would be nice if it used OS X's Facebook account integration to do so. The browser-based implementation requires me to use enter my two-factor authentication code because it's, well, a browser.

Comment: I've now finally started using this; what I miss the most from Newt is *new question notifications*. Could the app at the very least use my account favorite tags to notify me of new questions? A configurable tag list would be better still.

Comment: With Newt entirely broken now, I switched over entirely some time ago. I still do miss question notifications.

Comment: What happens after 1 December 2014? Will a final version be released, or can we expect a new beta? Also, does the app update itself (e.g. through Sparkle)?

Comment: @Kristof I will open source the app and release a new version before the beta expires. The app does not update itself.

Comment: When Dark Mode on Yosemite is enabled the menu icon for StackPop disappears. It looks like a fix should be as simple as swapping the alt and normal icons when Dark Mode is enabled.

Comment: I'll see if I can commit this feature into the repo on BitBucket

Comment: The repo is read only so I forked the project. Someone else would have to sign it though. It would be nice if Jacob could incorporate the one-line change I made into the original app. https://bitbucket.org/michael_savich/stackpop

Comment: Why the app have only hold reputation for the primary site?

Comment: @jherran The reputation notifications are only for the primary site because of [Stack Exchange API rate limiting](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle). Each additional site would require an additional request and run into these limits.

Comment: Is it possible to use beta sites as primary sites?

Answer (score 6):

If only it would also install using `brew cask install stackpop` as I started to ignore any app that doesn't have a cask.