# desktop alert with notificatons whenever a favourite tagged question will be asked

Tags: feature-request, questions, email

I am using Firefox browser and Ubuntu13.04. I am looking for an app,which will create a desktop alert with sounds,whenever any question included with my listed tags in my favourite list will be asked in *Stackoverflow.com*.

Is there any for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no app, *exactly* like that but two are pretty close (they don't have any annoying sounds).

These both run on Windows + Linux platforms and provide desktop alerts for favorited/tracked tags. Check out:

[***StackApplet:***](https://stackapps.com/q/83/7653)

[image: App thumb], built on the QT framework

[***New Q!:***](https://stackapps.com/q/587/7653)

[image: App thumb], Uses the Chrome browser for its engine.

Comment: I am Ubuntu13.04. Will it be helpful. I want also sounds and pop-up.

Comment: How to configure it ? for stackoverflow sites

Comment: Ubuntu is a Linux OS.  These apps should work on it.  Both apps have pop-ups.  If you want sounds, you'll have to make your own extension or modify the source for one of those two.

Comment: I just have installed it,now what I need to do ?

Comment: Installed what/which?  Also, I don't use either app, but they look fairly straightforward.  Play around with their settings and see what happens.

Comment: I installed Stackaplet.but didn't find any preferences. :(

Comment: See the screenshot on [the app page](http://stackapps.com/q/83/7653).  You can also post an "answer" there, if you have a problem or feature-request for that app.